Why do emasculatus and effeminatus mean the SAME thing, despite being formed the SAME way with OPPOSITE morphemes?
The etymological constructions of emasculatus and effeminatus are identical:

emasculatus < ex- + masculus + -atus
effeminatus < ex- + femina + -atus

Since masculus and femina are opposites, the logical conclusion should be these words are opposites too. But they are virtually synonyms:

emasculatus: made less male
effeminatus: made more female

These odd meanings were inherited by English in the verb emasculate and the adjective effeminate.
How did these words, which were formed the same way with opposite morphemes, end up meaning the same thing?

The meanings of ex- here are indeed odd, but I don't think these can be called "synonyms". According to Lewis & Short's Latin Dictionary, emasculare is to castrate, so emasculatus is castrated. One doesn't make something more feminine by castrating it: a castrated male animal doesn't behave like a female, but rather neuter or sexless.

@KotobaTrilyNgian "Virtually synonyms." I'm not aware of how progressive the Romans were about gender and sex, but at the very least making something less male is almost like making it more female. Regardless, debating about the precision of the synonymy detracts from why the same construction can yield two distinct results and that's not quite relevant here. My question is more concerned of why effiminatus doesn't simply mean "made less feminine" the same way emasculatus means "made less masculine."

See also effeminare = evirare (?)

@Asteroides Shouldn't this question be marked a duplicate of that? I don't see a substantial difference.

Closing for now. @Vun-Hugh Vaw: if you feel that the linked question doesn't fully answer your inquiry, you can always edit your question to take the new information into account and explain more about what you're looking for. We can take a look at re-opening it then.
